# Problem with unload() function (CS50 Week 5: Speller)

Tags: c, memory-management, cs50

I'm working on CS50's Week 5 assignment, Speller. I'm building my functions one at a time, and I'm running into problems with my `unload` function (Line 151). Right now, I'm just testing the iteration in a way that prints results before I use that iteration to free each of the nodes. I'm doing this by changing each node's word to `"FREE"` in the order these nodes are to be freed.

The function call (Line 60) returns true, and the `printf` command prints successfully. However, everything in the `unload` function itself is being ignored. None of the `printf` lines that I added to see its progress (`DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG`) are printing. The `print()` function call on line 63 should be printing the table with all of the words set to `"FREE"`, and all dictionary word locations showing `"NOT FOUND"`. Instead, it's printing the list and locations completely unaltered, and with none of the `DEBUG` print commands within the for loop (Line 155) triggering.

I don't understand why this is happening. The `unload()` function call alone, whether or not it returns true, should still at least trigger the first `printf` command in the for loop (Line 157). But even that is skipped.

Can someone please help me understand why the function is returning true, yet making none of the changes it's supposed to? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Okay, I was told that I wasn't calling the `unload` function correctly on line 60. I've since corrected that. Now it will print out `"LOCATION 00:"`, but it ends as soon as it hits that first `while` loop on line 158. I was having this problem before, and I'm not sure why it's doing this. `strcmp()` should see that the head node's word does not match `"FREE"` until it makes the change from the end of the list to the beginning. Why is the while loop not even triggering?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int HASH_MAX = 50; // Max elements in hash table
unsigned int LENGTH = 20; // Max length of word to be stored

unsigned int hash(const char *word); // assign hash code -- [(code + current letter) * 3] * string length, % HASH_MAX
bool load(FILE *dictionary); // load dictionary into memory
bool check(char *word); // check if word exists in dictionary
bool unload(void); // unload dictionary from memory, free memory (CURRENTLY DEBUGGING, CHECKING ITERATION)
void print(void); // print table contents and node locations

typedef struct _node // node structure: stored word, pointer to next node
{
    char *word[20];
    struct _node *next;
} node;

node *HASH_TABLE[50];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *dictionary = fopen("C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/Dictionary.txt", "r"); // open dictionary file, read

    if (!dictionary) // if dictionary is NULL, return error message, end program
    {
        printf("FILE NOT FOUND\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (load(dictionary)) // if dictionary loaded successfully (function call), close dictionary and print table contents
    {
        fclose(dictionary);
        print(); // print "LIST (number): {(name, address), ...}\n
    }

    char *checkword = "Albatross"; // test check function for word that does not exist in the library
    char *checkword2 = "Riku"; // test check function for word that does exist in the library

    if (check(checkword)) // return check results for checkword, found or not found
    {
        printf("\n%s found\n", checkword);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%s not found\n", checkword);
    }

    if (check(checkword2)) // return check results for checkword2, found or not found
    {
        printf("\n%s found\n", checkword2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%s not found\n", checkword2);
    }

    if (unload()) // if unloaded successfully (function call), print contents
    {
        printf("\nUNLOADED...\n\n"); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (confirm unload function returned true)
        print();
    }
}

unsigned int hash(const char *word) // assign hash code -- [(code + current letter) * 3] * string length, % HASH_MAX
{
    char word_conv[LENGTH + 1]; // store converted word for uniform key
    unsigned int code = 0; // hash code

    strcpy(word_conv, word);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) // set all letters in the word to lower case
    {
        word_conv[i] = tolower(word_conv[i]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word_conv); j++) // for all letters in converted word, add ascii value to code and multiply by 3
    {
        code += word_conv[j];
        code = code * 3;
    }

    code = code % HASH_MAX; // set code to remainder of current code divided by maximum hash table size

    return code;
}

bool load(FILE *dictionary) // load dictionary into memory
{
    char word[LENGTH+1]; // store next word in the dictionary

    while (!feof(dictionary)) // until end of dictionary file
    {
        fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word); // scan for next word

        node *new_n = malloc(sizeof(node)); // new node
        strcpy(new_n->word, word); // store scanned word in new node
        new_n->next = NULL; // new node's next pointer set to NULL

        unsigned int code = hash(word); // retrieve and store hash code

        if (HASH_TABLE[code] == NULL) // if hash location has no head
        {
            HASH_TABLE[code] = new_n; // set new node to location head
        }
        else if (HASH_TABLE[code] != NULL) // if head already exists at hash location
        {
            node *trav = HASH_TABLE[code]; // set traversal node

            while (trav->next != NULL) // while traversal node's next pointer is not NULL
            {
                trav = trav->next; // move to next node
            }

            if (trav->next == NULL) // if traversal node's next pointer is null
            {
                trav->next = new_n; // set new node to traversal node's next pointer
            }
        }
    }

    return true; // confirm successful load
}

bool check(char *word) // check if word exists in dictionary
{
    unsigned int code = hash(word); // retrieve and store hash code

    node *check = HASH_TABLE[code]; // set traversal node to hash location head

    while (check != NULL) // while traversal node is not NULL
    {
        int check_true = strcasecmp(check->word, word); // compare traversal node's word to provided word argument

        if (check_true == 0) // if a match is found, return true
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (check_true != 0) // if no match, move to next node
        {
            check = check->next;
        }
    }

    if (check == NULL) // if end of list is reached without a match, return false
        return false;
}

bool unload(void) // unload dictionary from memory, free memory (CURRENTLY DEBUGGING, CHECKING ITERATION)
{
    char *word = "FREE"; // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (changin all nodes' words to "FREE" to test iteration)

    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_MAX; i++) // for every element in the hash table, HASH_MAX (50)
    {
        printf("LOCATION %02d:\n", i); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (print current hash table location)
        while (strcmp(HASH_TABLE[i]->word, word) != 0) // while the head node's word is not "FREE"
        {
            node *trav = HASH_TABLE[i]; // set traversal node to head
            printf("HEAD WORD: %s\n", HASH_TABLE[i]->word); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (print head word to confirm while condition)

            while (strcmp(trav->next->word, word) != 0) // while the traversal node's word is not "FREE"
            {
                trav = trav->next; // move to next node
                printf("."); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (print a dot for every location skipped)
            }

            printf("\n"); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG

            strcpy(trav->word, word); // set traversal node's word to "FREE"

            printf("{"); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG

            while (trav != NULL) // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (print hash location's current list of words)
            {
                printf("%s, ", trav->word); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG
            }

            printf("}\n\n"); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG
        }
    }

    return true; // freed successfully
}

void print(void) // print hash table contents and node locations
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_MAX; i++) // for every element in the hash table
    {
        node *check = HASH_TABLE[i]; // set traversal node to current hash table element head

        printf("LIST %02d: {", i); // print hash table element location

        while (check != NULL) // for all nodes in the current linked list
        {
            printf("%s, ", check->word); // print traversal node's word
            check = check->next; // move to next node
        }

        printf("}\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    FILE *dictionary = fopen("C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/Dictionary.txt", "r"); // open dictionary file

    while (!feof(dictionary)) // for all words in the dictionary
    {
        char word[LENGTH + 1]; // store next word

        fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word); // scan for next word

        unsigned int code = hash(word); // retrieve and store word's hash code

        node *search = HASH_TABLE[code]; // set traversal node to hash location head

        while (search != NULL) // for all nodes at that location, or until word is found
        {
            if (strcasecmp(search->word, word) == 0) // compare traversal node's word to scanned word (case insensitive)
            {
                printf("%s: %p\n", search->word, search); // print traversal node's word and location
                break; // break while loop
            }
            else
            {
                search = search->next; // if traversal node's word does not match scanned word, move to next node
            }
        }

        if (search == NULL) // if the scanned word matches none of the words in the hash location's linked list
            printf("\"%s\" NOT FOUND\n", word); // word not found
    }

    fclose(dictionary); // close dictionary file
}
```

Comment: You're not calling the `unload` function, you're just expressing a pointer to it, and letting that pointer drop on the floor. You need to do say `unload()`.

Comment: Ah. You're right. Okay, I made that change. And now it's giving me "LOCATION 00:", but the program terminates after that. No print out. It gets as close as that first while loop on line 158, and then nothing.

Comment: You get the nod for a well written question with a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

*Caveat:* chqrlie has pointed out many of the basic issues, but here's some refactored code.

---

Your main issue was that `unload` didn't actually remove the nodes.

---

One of things to note is that it's easier/faster/better to use `tolower` *once* per string.

If the lowercased version is what we *store* in the node, and we lowercase the search word in `check`, we can use `strcmp` instead of `strcasecmp` [which has to redo the lowercasing for *both* arguments on *each* loop iteration].

So, I've changed the `hash` function to lowercase its argument "in-place".

---

As I mentioned in my above comment, `print` was extraneously rereading the dictionary file. So, I've removed that code. If it *were* necessary to do this, it should go into [yet] another function, or `load` and/or `check` should be reused.

(i.e.) `print` should *do one thing well* [a programming maxim].

---

Personally, I dislike "sidebar" comments:

```
if (unload()) // if unloaded successfully (function call), print contents
```

I prefer the comment to go above the line:

```
// if unloaded successfully (function call), print contents
if (unload())
```

To me, this is much clearer and it helps prevent the line from going beyond 80 characters in width.

---

Certain fixed constants (e.g. `HASH_MAX` and `LENGTH`) are global variables. This prevents them from being used to define arrays

(e.g.) you couldn't say:

```
node *HASH_TABLE[HASH_MAX];
```

and had to "hardwire" it as:

```
node *HASH_TABLE[50];
```

If we define these with either `#define` or as an `enum`, then we can use the preferred definitions.

---

Doing something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
```

increases the loop time from O(length) to O(length^2) because `strlen` is called "length" times inside the loop and it rescans the string each time.

Much better to do:

```
int len = strlen(word);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

But even this has an extra scan of the buffer. It can be better is to do something like:

```
for (int chr = *word++;  chr != 0;  chr = *word++)
```

---

I've refactored the code with annotations for the bugs. Original code is bracketed inside a `#if 0` block:

```
#if 0
// old/original code
#else
// new/refactored code
#endif
```

Anyway, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#if 1
#include <ctype.h>
#endif

// Max elements in hash table
#if 0
unsigned int HASH_MAX = 50;
#else
enum {
    HASH_MAX = 50
};
#endif

// Max length of word to be stored
#if 0
unsigned int LENGTH = 20;
#else
enum {
    LENGTH = 20
};
#endif

// assign hash code -- [(code + current letter) * 3] * string length, % HASH_MAX
#if 0
unsigned int hash(const char *word);
#else
unsigned int hash(char *word);
#endif

// load dictionary into memory
bool load(FILE *dictionary);

// check if word exists in dictionary
#if 0
bool check(char *word);
#else
bool check(const char *word);
#endif

// unload dictionary from memory, free memory (CURRENTLY DEBUGGING,
// CHECKING ITERATION)
bool unload(void);

// print table contents and node locations
void print(void);

// node structure: stored word, pointer to next node
typedef struct _node {
#if 0
    char *word[20];
#else
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
#endif
    struct _node *next;
} node;

#if 0
node *HASH_TABLE[50];
#else
node *HASH_TABLE[HASH_MAX];
#endif

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // open dictionary file, read
#if 0
    FILE *dictionary = fopen("C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/Dictionary.txt", "r");
#else
    FILE *dictionary = fopen("Dictionary.txt", "r");
#endif

    // if dictionary is NULL, return error message, end program
    if (!dictionary) {
        printf("FILE NOT FOUND\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // if dictionary loaded successfully (function call), close dictionary and
    // print table contents
    if (load(dictionary)) {
        fclose(dictionary);
        // print "LIST (number): {(name, address), ...}\n
        print();
    }

    // test check function for word that does not exist in the library
    char *checkword = "Albatross";

    // test check function for word that does exist in the library
    char *checkword2 = "Riku";

    // return check results for checkword, found or not found
    if (check(checkword)) {
        printf("\n%s found\n", checkword);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n%s not found\n", checkword);
    }

    // return check results for checkword2, found or not found
    if (check(checkword2)) {
        printf("\n%s found\n", checkword2);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n%s not found\n", checkword2);
    }

    // if unloaded successfully (function call), print contents
    if (unload()) {
        // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (confirm unload function returned true)
        printf("\nUNLOADED...\n\n");
        print();
    }
}

// assign hash code -- [(code + current letter) * 3] * string length, % HASH_MAX
unsigned int
hash(char *word)
{
    // store converted word for uniform key
#if 0
    char word_conv[LENGTH + 1];
#endif

    // hash code
    unsigned int code = 0;

#if 0
    strcpy(word_conv, word);

    // set all letters in the word to lower case
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        word_conv[i] = tolower(word_conv[i]);
    }

    // for all letters in converted word, add ascii value to code and multiply by 3
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word_conv); j++) {
        code += word_conv[j];
        code = code * 3;
    }
#else
    int chr;
    while (1) {
        chr = *word;

        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        chr = tolower(chr);
        *word++ = chr;

        code += chr;
        code *= 3;
    }
#endif

    // set code to remainder of current code divided by maximum hash table size
    code = code % HASH_MAX;

    return code;
}

// load dictionary into memory
bool
load(FILE * dictionary)
{
    // store next word in the dictionary
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // until end of dictionary file
// NOTE/BUG: don't use feof
#if 0
    while (!feof(dictionary)) {
        // scan for next word
        fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word);
#else
    // scan for next word
    while (fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word) == 1) {
#endif
        // new node
        node *new_n = malloc(sizeof(node));

        // store scanned word in new node
        strcpy(new_n->word, word);
        // new node's next pointer set to NULL
        new_n->next = NULL;

        // retrieve and store hash code
        unsigned int code = hash(new_n->word);

        // NOTE/BUG: there's no need to append to the end of the list -- pushing
        // on the front is adequate and is faster
#if 0
        // if hash location has no head
        if (HASH_TABLE[code] == NULL) {
            // set new node to location head
            HASH_TABLE[code] = new_n;
        }
        // if head already exists at hash location
        else if (HASH_TABLE[code] != NULL) {
            // set traversal node
            node *trav = HASH_TABLE[code];

            // while traversal node's next pointer is not NULL
            while (trav->next != NULL) {
                // move to next node
                trav = trav->next;
            }

            // if traversal node's next pointer is null
            if (trav->next == NULL) {
                // set new node to traversal node's next pointer
                trav->next = new_n;
            }
        }
#else
        new_n->next = HASH_TABLE[code];
        HASH_TABLE[code] = new_n;
#endif
    }

    // confirm successful load
    return true;
}

// check if word exists in dictionary
#if 0
bool
check(char *word)
#else
bool
check(const char *arg)
#endif
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // retrieve and store hash code
#if 1
    strcpy(word,arg);
#endif
    unsigned int code = hash(word);

    // set traversal node to hash location head
    node *check = HASH_TABLE[code];

    // while traversal node is not NULL
    while (check != NULL) {
        // compare traversal node's word to provided word argument
// NOTE/BUG: strcmp is faster than strcasecmp if we convert to lowercase _once_
#if 0
        int check_true = strcasecmp(check->word, word);
#else
        int check_true = strcmp(check->word, word);
#endif

#if 0
        // if a match is found, return true
        if (check_true == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        // if no match, move to next node
        else if (check_true != 0) {
            check = check->next;
        }
#else
        if (check_true == 0)
            return true;

        check = check->next;
#endif
    }

    // if end of list is reached without a match, return false
#if 0
    if (check == NULL)
        return false;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}

// unload dictionary from memory, free memory
// (CURRENTLY DEBUGGING, CHECKING ITERATION)
bool
unload(void)
{
    // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (changin all nodes' words to "FREE" to test iteration)
#if 0
    char *word = "FREE";
#endif

    // for every element in the hash table, HASH_MAX (50)
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_MAX; i++) {
#if 0
        // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (print current hash table location)
        printf("LOCATION %02d:\n", i);
        // while the head node's word is not "FREE"
        while (strcmp(HASH_TABLE[i]->word, word) != 0) {
            // set traversal node to head
            node *trav = HASH_TABLE[i];

            // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (print head word to confirm while condition)
            printf("HEAD WORD: %s\n", HASH_TABLE[i]->word);

            // while the traversal node's word is not "FREE"
            while (strcmp(trav->next->word, word) != 0) {
                // move to next node
                trav = trav->next;
                // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (print a dot for every location skipped)
                printf(".");
            }

            // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG
            printf("\n");

            // set traversal node's word to "FREE"
            strcpy(trav->word, word);

            // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG
            printf("{");

            // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (print hash location's current list of words)
            while (trav != NULL) {
                // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG
                printf("%s, ", trav->word);
            }

            // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG
            printf("}\n\n");
        }
#else
        node *nxt;
        for (node *cur = HASH_TABLE[i];  cur != NULL;  cur = nxt) {
            nxt = cur->next;
            free(cur);
        }
        HASH_TABLE[i] = NULL;
#endif
    }

    // freed successfully
    return true;
}

// print hash table contents and node locations
void
print(void)
{
    // for every element in the hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_MAX; i++) {
        // set traversal node to current hash table element head
        node *check = HASH_TABLE[i];

        // print hash table element location
        printf("LIST %02d: {", i);

        // for all nodes in the current linked list
        while (check != NULL) {
            // print traversal node's word
            printf("%s, ", check->word);
            // move to next node
            check = check->next;
        }

        printf("}\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

// NOTE/BUG: why reread dictionary after printing it?
#if 0
    // open dictionary file
    FILE *dictionary = fopen("C:/Users/aaron/Desktop/Dictionary.txt", "r");

    // for all words in the dictionary
    while (!feof(dictionary)) {
        // store next word
        char word[LENGTH + 1];

        // scan for next word
        fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word);

        // retrieve and store word's hash code
        unsigned int code = hash(word);

        // set traversal node to hash location head
        node *search = HASH_TABLE[code];

        // for all nodes at that location, or until word is found
        while (search != NULL) {
            // compare traversal node's word to scanned word (case insensitive)
            if (strcasecmp(search->word, word) == 0) {
                // print traversal node's word and location
                printf("%s: %p\n", search->word, search);
                // break while loop
                break;
            }
            else {
                // if traversal node's word does not match scanned word,
                // move to next node
                search = search->next;
            }
        }

        // if the scanned word matches none of the words in the hash location's
        // linked list
        if (search == NULL)
            // word not found
            printf("\"%s\" NOT FOUND\n", word);
    }

    // close dictionary file
    fclose(dictionary);
#endif
}
```

---

Here's a version that has the `#if 0` blocks removed.

Also, I've added a slight reordering in the `load` function, so that it inputs the data *directly* into the final place inside the `node` element (i.e. eliminates the intermediate buffer and a `strcpy`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Max elements in hash table
enum {
    HASH_MAX = 50
};

// Max length of word to be stored
enum {
    LENGTH = 20
};

// assign hash code -- [(code + current letter) * 3] * string length, % HASH_MAX
unsigned int hash(char *word);

// load dictionary into memory
bool load(FILE *dictionary);

// check if word exists in dictionary
bool check(const char *word);

// unload dictionary from memory, free memory (CURRENTLY DEBUGGING,
// CHECKING ITERATION)
bool unload(void);

// print table contents and node locations
void print(void);

// node structure: stored word, pointer to next node
typedef struct _node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct _node *next;
} node;

node *HASH_TABLE[HASH_MAX];

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // open dictionary file, read
    FILE *dictionary = fopen("Dictionary.txt", "r");

    // if dictionary is NULL, return error message, end program
    if (!dictionary) {
        printf("FILE NOT FOUND\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // if dictionary loaded successfully (function call), close dictionary and
    // print table contents
    if (load(dictionary)) {
        fclose(dictionary);
        // print "LIST (number): {(name, address), ...}\n
        print();
    }

    // test check function for word that does not exist in the library
    char *checkword = "Albatross";

    // test check function for word that does exist in the library
    char *checkword2 = "Riku";

    // return check results for checkword, found or not found
    if (check(checkword)) {
        printf("\n%s found\n", checkword);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n%s not found\n", checkword);
    }

    // return check results for checkword2, found or not found
    if (check(checkword2)) {
        printf("\n%s found\n", checkword2);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n%s not found\n", checkword2);
    }

    // if unloaded successfully (function call), print contents
    if (unload()) {
        // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG (confirm unload function returned true)
        printf("\nUNLOADED...\n\n");
        print();
    }
}

// assign hash code -- [(code + current letter) * 3] * string length, % HASH_MAX
unsigned int
hash(char *word)
{
    // store converted word for uniform key

    // hash code
    unsigned int code = 0;

    unsigned char chr;
    while (1) {
        chr = *word;

        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        chr = tolower(chr);
        *word++ = chr;

        code += chr;
        code *= 3;
    }

    // set code to remainder of current code divided by maximum hash table size
    code = code % HASH_MAX;

    return code;
}

// load dictionary into memory
bool
load(FILE *dictionary)
{

    // scan for next word
    while (1) {
        // new node
        node *new_n = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (fscanf(dictionary, "%s", new_n->word) != 1) {
            free(new_n);
            break;
        }

        // store scanned word in new node
        new_n->next = NULL;

        // retrieve and store hash code
        unsigned int code = hash(new_n->word);

        // pushing on the front of the list is adequate and is faster
        new_n->next = HASH_TABLE[code];
        HASH_TABLE[code] = new_n;
    }

    // confirm successful load
    return true;
}

// check if word exists in dictionary
bool
check(const char *arg)
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // retrieve and store hash code
    strcpy(word,arg);
    unsigned int code = hash(word);

    // set traversal node to hash location head
    node *check = HASH_TABLE[code];

    // while traversal node is not NULL
    while (check != NULL) {
        // compare traversal node's word to provided word argument
        int check_true = strcmp(check->word, word);

        if (check_true == 0)
            return true;

        check = check->next;
    }

    // if end of list is reached without a match, return false
    return false;
}

// unload dictionary from memory, free memory
// (CURRENTLY DEBUGGING, CHECKING ITERATION)
bool
unload(void)
{

    // for every element in the hash table, HASH_MAX (50)
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_MAX; i++) {
        node *nxt;
        for (node *cur = HASH_TABLE[i];  cur != NULL;  cur = nxt) {
            nxt = cur->next;
            free(cur);
        }
        HASH_TABLE[i] = NULL;
    }

    // freed successfully
    return true;
}

// print hash table contents and node locations
void
print(void)
{
    // for every element in the hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_MAX; i++) {
        // set traversal node to current hash table element head
        node *check = HASH_TABLE[i];

        // print hash table element location
        printf("LIST %02d: {", i);

        // for all nodes in the current linked list
        while (check != NULL) {
            // print traversal node's word
            printf("%s, ", check->word);

            // move to next node
            check = check->next;
        }

        printf("}\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Could you please explain `for (int chr = *word++;  chr != 0;  chr = *word++)`? I don't know what `*word++` means in this context.

Sure. With `chr = *word++;` it means dereference `word` [a `char` pointer]. This fetches the `char` value pointed to by `word` (i.e. fetch the value from memory). Then, set this value into `chr`. Then, increment `word` [so it points to the *next* character in the array.

The statement is composed of three operators: `=` is the assignment operator. `*` is a dereference operator and `++` is a *post-decrement* operator.

Based on the precedence [and/or binding] of the operators, `*` has higher precedence [tighter binding], so it is performed first. The value is placed in `chr`. Then, `++` is performed on the value in `word`. It is as the following is performed as a single statement:

```
chr = *word;
word += 1;
```

---

> `chr = tolower(chr);` should be `chr = tolower((unsigned char)chr);` for reasons explained in my answer. Alternatively, you could define `chr` as `unsigned char chr;`

I was under the impression that `tolower` et. al. were "self protective" of this (e.g. they did the `unsigned char` cast). But, the [linux] manpage says its UB if the value is out of range. I've edited the second example to use `unsigned char chr;`.

Strangely, for glibc's `tolower`, it *has* a range check built it that works on the `int` value and returns the original value (i.e. does *not* index into the translation table) if the value is out of range. This appears to be part of some BSD compatibility [the BSD manpage states it does a range check, but the feature is deprecated]. I'm guessing the glibc range check as added after the manpage was written.

To me, the macro should just do the cast itself [and the global function as well]. But, I think this might break the BSD compatibility.

But, now we're all hamstrung to the old way [or add a wrapper macro] because of backward compatibility.

---

> it is confusing for `hash` to have a side effect on its argument and further confusing that this side effect be necessary for the `strcmp` in `check` to work.

The side effect is [probably] no more [or, perhaps, even less] egregious than what `strtok` does. That is, it's not modifying a hidden/unrelated global, etc.

IMO, it wouldn't be confusing if the effect were commented [I documented it in the answer text]. Perhaps renaming `hash` to something a bit more descriptive would help. We could do: `take_hash_of_argument_that_we_modify_to_lowercase_first`.

That would make the function name "self documenting" as some (e.g. "Uncle" Bob Martin(?)) *might* suggest member functions should be.

But, maybe `hash_and_lowercase` might be better. This might be a sufficient clue to the reader that they *need* to consult the API documentation for the function rather than assuming they know all about it from just the name.

The linked list traversal is much faster with `strcmp`, so, at a minimum [architecturally] we want to store lower case strings in the nodes. We don't want to repeat the lowercasing for each node on each scan. And, we don't want `strcasecmp` to repeat the lowercasing on `word` [and the string in the node] for each loop iteration.

As you say, we *could* have two functions. And we could still achieve this refactoring: a string based version of `tolower` that lowercases its argument and leave the `hash` as it was done originally.

Originally, I considered this approach. I soon realized that everywhere you did a hash, you wanted it to be on the lowercased string. We could achieve this with (e.g.):

```
strlower(word);
value = hash(word);
```

But, there wasn't a use case here for doing one of these calls separately--only in pairs.

So, given that, why scan the argument string *twice* and slow down the operation by 2x?

> From JFK [after the failed Bay of Pigs invasion]: *Mistakes* are not *errors* if we *admit* them.

So, I'd paraphrase that as: *Side effects* are not *errors* if we *document* them.

Comment: Thanks for continuing the discussion.

1) I understand your reasoning behind using `tolower()` once per string. Fewer function calls means faster code (if I understand correctly). But I've always been told to "idiot-proof" my code. What if the end user loses track of capslock and searches `"wORD"` instead of `"Word"`?

2) What would be the difference between `#define LENGTH 20` and the `ENUM` type you set (which I haven't seen until now), and why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: 3) Could you please explain `for (int chr = *word++;  chr != 0;  chr = *word++)`? I don't know what `*word++` means in this context.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: `chr = tolower(chr);` should be `chr = tolower((unsigned char)chr);` for reasons explained in my answer. Alternatively, you could define `chr` as `unsigned char chr;`

Comment: Much improved version... Just one remark: it is confusing for `hash` to have a side effect on its argument and further confusing that this side effect be necessary for the `strcmp` in `check` to work. As you mention, a function should do one thing only. A more readable approach would use `strlwr()` both in `load()` and in `check()` or a custom function that uses `tolower()`.

Comment: @chqrlie Ack on the need for the cast. But, I've added some rationale for why I think the [limited scope] side effect is reasonable for the use case.

Comment: It's a shame there is no "Educator" badge. (that's probably the most important badge of all on a site like this)

Comment: *Based on the precedence [and/or binding] of the operators, `*` has higher precedence [tighter binding], so it is performed first. The value is placed in `chr`. Then, `++` is performed on the value in `word`* Not really: `chr = *word++;` is indeed equivalent to `chr = *word; word += 1;` but not for the reason stated. Postfix operators bind stronger than prefix operators. Hence `++` is applied first, then `*`, but the side effect of `++` on `word` occurs at an unspecified time before the next sequence point and the value of `word++` is that of `word` **before** the increment.

Comment: *To me, the macro should just do the cast itself [and the global function as well].* This is not the solution because all functions in `<ctype.h>` are defined for all values returned by `getc()`, ie: all values of type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. Adding an implicit cast in `tolower()` would make `EOF` indistinguishable from `'\xff'`, which may or may not be adequate. The real problem is that type `char` can be signed by default, which is fundamentally in inconsistent with the semantics of many C library functions.

Comment: The extra range support in the Glibc and the BSD C library allowing defined behavior for `tolower` and other `<ctype.h>` for values between `-128` and `255` is a hack to try and mitigate the problem, but it still has problems: in many locales, `'\xff'` represents the letter `ÿ` but has the same value as `EOF` if `char` is signed, hence `islower('ÿ')` cannot be true even in the `fr_FR` locale.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the `word` member of the `_node` structure has the wrong type: it should just be an array of 20 characters, not an array of 20 char pointers. And dont use `_node`, identifiers starting with `_` are reserved. Change the definition to:

  ```
    typedef struct node { // node structure: stored word, pointer to next node
        char word[LENGTH+1];
        struct node *next;
    } node;
  ```
- your reading loops are incorrect: `while (!feof(dictionary))` is not the proper test to detect the end of file, you should instead test if `fscanf()` successfully reads the next word:

  ```
    while (fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word) == 1) // until end of dictionary file
  ```

  Furthermore you should specify a maximum length for `fscanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on long words:

  ```
    while (fscanf(dictionary, "%19s", word) == 1) // read at most 19 characters
  ```
- You do not check for allocation failure.
- There are many redundant tests such as `else if (HASH_TABLE[code] != NULL)` and `if (trav->next == NULL)` in `load()`, `else if (check_true != 0)` and `if (check == NULL)` in `check()`.
- You do not modify `trav` in the loop `while (trav != NULL)` in the DEBUG code, causing an infinite loop.

It is not difficult to free the dictionary in `unload()`, your iteration checking code is way too complicated, you already have correct iteration code for `print()`. Here is a simple example:

```c
bool unload(void) { // unload dictionary from memory, free memory
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_MAX; i++) {
        while (HASH_TABLE[i]) {
            node *n = HASH_TABLE[i];
            HASH_TABLE[i] = n->next;
            free(n);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note also that there is no need to store the converted word to compute the hash value, and `char` values must be cast as `(unsigned char)` to pass to `tolower()` because this function is only defined for the values of `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. `char` may be a signed type, so `tolower(word[i])` has undefined behavior for extended characters.

```c
unsigned int hash(const char *word) // assign hash code -- [(code + current letter) * 3] * string length, % HASH_MAX
{
    unsigned int code = 0; // hash code

    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        // compute hashcode from lowercase letters
        code = (code + tolower((unsigned char)word[i])) * 3;
    }

    code = code % HASH_MAX; // set code to remainder of current code divided by maximum hash table size

    return code;
}
```

Comment: In OP's code, in `print`, after printing all the nodes, it has [extraneous] code that reopens the dictionary file, and does things that look like some parts of `load` and `check`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been extremely helpful. I'm learning on my own, and it's easy to get confused. Perhaps you can answer a couple more questions for me?

I've never been clear on the difference between a signed variable and an unsigned variable, let alone when to use either.

I'm aware of my redundant checks, but I've always had a problem using "else" confidently. Whenever I do, things seem to go wrong. As though there are other conditions I'm not accounting for. So, even though I know it's a bad habit, I've just been deliberately checking for specific conditions.

Comment: @CraigEstey Well, I originally only had the file open once. But in print(), I'm checking through the list again, in the order the dictionary lists these words, to make sure they all return addresses. But it seems that since I've already read to the end of the file in load(), it would not read from the beginning unless I opened it again.

Sorry if my comment formatting is bad. I don't really understand how it works yet.